# Does windmove support wrap around navigation in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm using windmove to switch between windows. Per default, windmove does not wrap around, for example, `windmove-up` will fail when you are already at the top of the window. However, I want it to wrap around and navigate to the bottom window.

I managed to get it working but the solution is quite a hack (if there is an error just reverse the direction and continue until it fails again):

```
(define-key my-keys-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-M-k") (lambda () (interactive)
                            (unless
                                (ignore-errors (windmove-up))
                                (while (ignore-errors (windmove-down)) ()))))
```

Is there a more elegant solution? Does windmove provide a straightforward way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
M-x customize-variable RET windmove-wrap-around RET
```

Is that it? The variable is basically at the top of `windmove.el`.

If you don't want to open the source file,

```
M-x customize-group RET windmove RET
```

would show you all customizable variables belonging to this mode. Both of them.

Comment: Funny, I am about to refer to Dimitri's switch-window.el

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Now I added `(setq windmove-wrap-around t)` to my .emacs file.

Answer (score 1):

For changing windows, you might want to try [this](https://github.com/dimitri/switch-window/blob/master/switch-window.el) package:

`switch-window`: when invoked, it allows you to select a window from choice (it overlays numeric choices from 1 to the amount of windows over the windows). Choosing a number will switch to the associated window.

This might be even easier to use for navigation of window purposes. As for a direct question of your answer, I would indeed program it in a similar way, though I would also suppose there is a more suitable answer.

Comment: It's a nice package indeed, I use it together with `windmove`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.emacs` file:

```
(setq windmove-wrap-around t)
```